# How can I remove this extra character from my string?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a string that is stored in an array, and eventually inserted into a SQL database using php and PDO.  When I look in the database there is an =20 that gets stored at the end of the string that I would like to get rid of.

My code looks something like this:

```
$name = trim($message_item[1]);
$name = addslashes($name);
$so_row = "INSERT into sales_order (name) VALUES('$name')";
$dbmrp->exec($so_row);
```

I thought that trim() would remove anything extra, but it doesn't seem to help.  I can get rid of it using preg_replace('/\s+/','',$name), but then I lose all the whitespace, including the ones in the middle that I want to keep.  So what is =20 and how do I get rid of it?

*more info-*  $message_item is an array that is created from exploding a string that gets read from an email.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections! Please learn how to use prepared statements!

Comment: What is it you desire to trim? Spaces or '=20'?

Comment: What is `$message_item` and where does it come from? The Big Question is - where does the `=20` come from in the first place?

Comment: I'd like the name to be stored in the database without the =20 ending up there.  If I just output $name I don't see any extra characters, so I was assuming that it was the result of some sort of space.  The $message_item is something that gets read from an email message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim is only for spaces on the beginning and the end of string.
You can do as Donovan said and remove all 3 last caracter.

```
$name = substr($name, 0, -3);
```

or replace all =20 by empty

```
str_replace('=20', '', subject)
```

But I really think you should figure out why you are getting an string with this =20. Any solution that remove it, is nothing but an workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr()` to remove "=20" at the end of your string like.

```
$name = substr($name, 0, -3);
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php

Comment: I tried something similar, but used -1, since it's really just a single invisible item that gets translated to =20 in the process of going into the database.  The problem with doing it that way though is that sometimes the extra character is there and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Check the encoding in your database. But I can't see the problem.. Can you write the value of $so_row just before you insert in your base?

Comment: Well, OK, I guess the =20 is there before.  Apparently in this particular case the =20 wasn't on the name, but it appears on others.  So maybe one of the preg replace solutions would work.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
rtrim($mesage_item[1], '=20');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = preg_replace('/=20$/', '', $name);
```